# Run "open" in elgato streamdeck without opening console

Tags: python, windows, streamdeck

I'm trying to run a python script from an elgato streamdeck, the code works properly but everytime i run it through my streamdeck it breifly opens a CMD window.
my goal is to run the script "silently"
I already changed the .py to a .pyw, which should run it without a window opening, but the problem seems to come from the elgato app

Any thoughts on how i could do that ?

Comment: I don't think you can "double click" a Python file and not have it try to open cmd.

Comment: yeah you can double click an have no window opening (that's what the .pyw is for), try a simple script and save it both as .py and .pyw, you'll know what i mean

Comment: Sure. Perhaps, as you say, the elgato app has its own "script wrapper". For example, calling `python app.pyw` in a `.bat` file, then executing that still should open one cmd window for the batch script

Answer (score 1):

runing my python script from a .bat file seems to have fix the issue, thx OneCricketeer :)